# I want to add .html at the end or a full url fetch from Database and php query between echo

Tags: php

I am going to write following code for my blog. But problem, I am facing with:

`"echo 'a href=".$query2['url']."</a>';`"  I want to add `.$query2['url'].` in `echo` and also want to add .html at the end of url like 
"`a href=".$query2['url'].html.`".

If you have any idea please tell me as soon as possible thanks. Basically I am fetching this data from database .

```
<?php
$start=0;
$limit=5;

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $start=($id-1)*$limit;
}

$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services LIMIT $start, $limit");
echo "<div class='entry'>";
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
       echo '<a href=".$query2['url']."><h2>' .$query2['name'].'</h2></a>';
    echo "<p>".$query2['Contents']."</p>";
    echo "<div class='meta'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i>".$query2['date'].  "<b><i class='fa fa-user'></i></b>  Written by <strong>Arslan Ali</strong>   <b><i class='fa fa-comment-o'></i></b>"  ;
echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";

$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from tbl_services"));
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);

echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
if($id>1)
{
    echo "<li><a href='?id=".($id-1)."' class='disabled'><<</a></li>";
}
        for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
        {
            if($i==$id) { echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>"; }

            else { echo "<li><a href='?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>"; }
        }
if($id!=$total)
{
        echo "<li><a href='?id=".($id+1)."' class='disabled'>>></a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Updated)**
Replace this line

```
echo '<a href=".$query2['url']."><h2>' .$query2['name'].'</h2></a>';
```

with

```
echo "<a href='".$query2['url'].".html'>".$query2['name']."</a>";
```

Comment: Same Error and also want to add .html at the end of .$query2['url']. in url

Comment: appropriate handle @Syntax Error.  Missing single quote after `href"`  and before `"><h2>'`

Comment: Thanks @SyntaxError You solved a big prob for me thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to tell you. It was easier to just write out the whole thing in a separate answer.

Comment: @SyntaxError just tell me one more thing please I want to add data as DESC how I can do this ???

Comment: @ArslanAli For this you have to modify your sql query a bit. Just add `ORDER BY column_name DESC` at the end of your mysql query. Don't forget to replace your own column name with 'column_name '

Comment: @SyntaxError
$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services LIMIT $start, $limit");
$rows=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from tbl_services"));

I have add these two queries which will i modify ??

Comment: @ArslanAli First tell me what is the name of primary key column? I will write you the query. Normally the primary key is the first column in the database. Tell me the exact name of first column in your `tbl_services`

Comment: @SyntaxError
its id
basically it select "ID" as primary key

Comment: change this line `$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services LIMIT $start, $limit");` to this: `$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");`

Comment: @SyntaxError I also have second keu with name cid 
I want to fetch data with both primary key "ID" and with "CID" like 
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $start=($id-1)*$limit;
}
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id=$_GET['cid'];
    $start=($cid-1)*$limit;
}

Comment: in that case, change this line `$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services LIMIT $start, $limit");` to this: `$query=mysql_query("select * from tbl_services ORDER BY $id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit");`

Answer (score 1):

There is still one problem with the solution made by Syntax Error.  The href is in single quotes.  This is not the proper Syntax. It is easily remedied by reversing the use of the single and double quotes as I have shown here.

```
echo '<a href="' . $query2['url'] . '.html">' . $query2['name']. '</a>';
```